# Magento 2 : Get Customer Data using knockout js in checkout page

Tags: magento2, onepage-checkout, knockoutjs

While placing the order if customer is not login and after entering email address if customer is already register with us then i need to display first name of customer with message below the email address input box.

[image]

Comment: have you find the solution?

Comment: no @aravind still looking for solution

Comment: Have you try anything?

Comment: Check if the account is log in.